# Getting subscription_id element from JSON file

Tags: php, json, laravel, chargify

now I have a function and I would like to subtract the subscription_id from the JSON code it transmit to the Chargify website but I'm not sure how to do.

This is the main function

```
public function reactivateSubscription2()
    {
        $chargify = new \Crucial\Service\Chargify([
            'hostname'   =>  //,
            'api_key'    =>  //,
            'shared_key' =>  //
        ]);

        $subscription = $chargify->subscription()


            ->reactivate(1234); // 1234 is the ID number

        return redirect()->action('WebhookController@postChargify')->with('account', [ [ 'msg' => 'Thank you for your activation, please refresh this page after 30 seconds, thank you.', 'type' => 'success', 'icon' => 'fa-check']]);
```

when we have

```
->reactivate(1234); // 1234 is the ID number
```

I just want to get the subscription ID for the user when the user is logged on and do the command. Here's the JSON code.

```
{"subscription"=>
  {"id"=>17674824,
   "state"=>"canceled",
   "trial_started_at"=>Tue, 09 May 2017 15:01:50 EDT -04:00,
   "trial_ended_at"=>Thu, 08 Jun 2017 15:01:50 EDT -04:00,
   "activated_at"=>Thu, 04 May 2017 15:09:04 EDT -04:00,
   "created_at"=>Wed, 03 May 2017 14:18:19 EDT -04:00,
   "updated_at"=>Thu, 11 May 2017 16:08:57 EDT -04:00,
   "expires_at"=>nil,
   "balance_in_cents"=>0,
   "current_period_ends_at"=>Sun, 11 Jun 2017 16:08:32 EDT -04:00,
   "next_assessment_at"=>Sun, 11 Jun 2017 16:08:32 EDT -04:00,
   "canceled_at"=>Thu, 11 May 2017 16:08:53 EDT -04:00,
   "cancellation_message"=>nil,
   "next_product_id"=>nil,
   "cancel_at_end_of_period"=>false,
   "payment_collection_method"=>"automatic",
   "snap_day"=>nil,
   "cancellation_method"=>"merchant_ui",
   "current_period_started_at"=>Thu, 11 May 2017 16:08:32 EDT -04:00,
   "previous_state"=>"active",
   "signup_payment_id"=>184515899,
   "signup_revenue"=>"0.00",
   "delayed_cancel_at"=>nil,
   "coupon_code"=>nil,
   "total_revenue_in_cents"=>95990,
   "product_price_in_cents"=>999,
   "product_version_number"=>1,
   "payment_type"=>"credit_card",
   "referral_code"=>"8gx4bk",
   "coupon_use_count"=>nil,
   "coupon_uses_allowed"=>nil,
   "reason_code"=>"CH:Unknown",
   "automatically_resume_at"=>nil,
   "customer"=>
    {"id"=>17209166,
     "first_name"=>"Zhiyu",
     "last_name"=>"Pu",
     "organization"=>nil,
     "email"=>"georgepuww45@gmail.com",
     "created_at"=>Wed, 03 May 2017 14:18:19 EDT -04:00,
     "updated_at"=>Thu, 04 May 2017 15:26:07 EDT -04:00,
     "reference"=>"georgepuww45@gmail.com",
     "address"=>nil,
     "address_2"=>nil,
     "city"=>nil,
     "state"=>nil,
     "zip"=>nil,
     "country"=>"CA",
     "phone"=>nil,
     "portal_invite_last_sent_at"=>nil,
     "portal_invite_last_accepted_at"=>nil,
     "verified"=>false,
     "portal_customer_created_at"=>nil,
     "cc_emails"=>nil,
     "tax_exempt"=>false},
   "product"=>
    {"id"=>3889616,
     "name"=>"Xert Premium Monthly",
     "handle"=>"prm-mth",
     "description"=>"",
     "accounting_code"=>"",
     "request_credit_card"=>true,
     "expiration_interval"=>nil,
     "expiration_interval_unit"=>"never",
     "created_at"=>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 00:29:41 EDT -04:00,
     "updated_at"=>Wed, 10 Aug 2016 00:29:41 EDT -04:00,
     "price_in_cents"=>999,
     "interval"=>1,
     "interval_unit"=>"month",
     "initial_charge_in_cents"=>nil,
     "trial_price_in_cents"=>nil,
     "trial_interval"=>nil,
     "trial_interval_unit"=>"day",
     "archived_at"=>nil,
     "require_credit_card"=>true,
     "return_params"=>"",
     "taxable"=>true,
     "update_return_url"=>"",
     "initial_charge_after_trial"=>true,
     "version_number"=>1,
     "update_return_params"=>"",
     "product_family"=>
      {"id"=>588123,
       "name"=>"Billing Plans",
       "description"=>nil,
       "handle"=>"baron-biosystems-billing-plans",
       "accounting_code"=>nil},
     "public_signup_pages"=>[]},
   "credit_card"=>
    {"id"=>11910433,
     "first_name"=>"George",
     "last_name"=>"Pu",
     "masked_card_number"=>"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1111",
     "card_type"=>"visa",
     "expiration_month"=>11,
     "expiration_year"=>2020,
     "customer_id"=>17209166,
     "current_vault"=>"bogus",
     "vault_token"=>"1",
     "billing_address"=>"",
     "billing_city"=>"",
     "billing_state"=>"",
     "billing_zip"=>"",
     "billing_country"=>"CA",
     "customer_vault_token"=>nil,
     "billing_address_2"=>nil,
     "payment_type"=>"credit_card"}},
 "site"=>{"id"=>, "subdomain"=>""},
 "event_id"=>}
```

Comment: I feel like using `return redirect()->action('WebhookController@postChargify') ...` is attempting a `GET` request on that action, which as defined by your routes is not allowed. You could use `app()->make(WebhookController::class)->postChargify();`, but I'm not sure what you'd put in the parameters of `postChargify()`

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you and yes it's been pretty confusing to see the (Request $request) and I'm not sure about that too.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Either be ok with `Route::get` or use Guzzle or cURL to simulate a POST to it. You can't redirect to a route expecting post.